# Get value of variable from inner class

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a method that implement a class inside it:

```
public class RetrofitCallBackUtil {
    private ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();


    public ArrayList<Message> getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, int sender_id, int offset_number, RESTDatabaseDAO service) {
        Call<ArrayList<Message>> call = service.getLastTenMessage(user_id, sender_id, offset_number);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Response<ArrayList<Message>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    messages = response.body();
                    Log.i("Success", "Good ten " + response.body().size());
                } else {
                    Log.i("Success", "Not good  ten" + response.raw());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("Fail", "Failure ten " + t.toString());
            }
        });
        //Still get NullPointException from here. (messages.size())
        Log.i("Success", "Good ten activity" + messages.size());
        return messages;
    }

}
```

I want to get value of messages variable but cannot. I also create a global variable `List<Message> messages` and return but still cannot get value from `response.body()`. Anybody have solution for this?

**UPDATE:**

I want something like this:

```
List<Message>  testMessages = retrofitCallBackUtil.getLastTenMessageCallBack(AppConfig.USER_ID, userId, 0, service);
```

Because I want to use the result of that method many time and many place so I want it return me a data.

Comment: Try `messages.addAll(response.body());` instead of `messages = response.body();`

Comment: @saka1029 still null :D

Comment: It will be filled when `onResponse()` is executed.

Comment: I run it again with your suggestion but still get size of list is 0 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onResponse` and `onFailure` are asynchronously called, so when you are trying to `return messages;`, it is not updated yet.

return it from within the callbacks.

Edit 1:

```
public void getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, int sender_id, int offset_number, RESTDatabaseDAO service) {
     Call<ArrayList<Message>> call = service.getLastTenMessage(user_id, sender_id, offset_number);
     call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Message>>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Response<ArrayList<Message>> response) {
               if (response.isSuccess()) {
           // THIS IS BEING CALLED AFTER YOUR METHODS RETURNS, SO UPDATE YOUR VIEWS LIKE THIS.

            updateViews(response.body());
            Log.i("Success", "Good ten " + response.body().size());
        } else {
            Log.i("Success", "Not good  ten" + response.raw());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i("Fail", "Failure ten " + t.toString());
    }
   });


}
public void updateViews(List<Messages> messages){
    //use messages to update your views here.
}
```

Edit 2: now since you are calling it from many places, pass something like requestCode and check the the same onResponse to identify the origin of the call.

```
public void getLastTenMessageCallBack(final int requestCode, int user_id, ..
```

and `onResponse`

```
updateViews(requestCode, response.body());
```

and update your views accordingly by comparing the request code.

```
public void updateViews(int requestCode, List<Messages> messages){
    if(requestCode==XYZ)
    //use messages to update your views here.
}
```

Edit 3:
Define your own `interface` to receive callbacks:

```
public interface NetworkResponseCallback {
   void onSuccess(ArrayList<Message>> messages);
   void onFailure(); //if you want to pass something else, like cause of failure you can add it.
}
```

Now, change your method definition:

```
public void getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, ... , final NetworkResponseCallback networkResponseCallback){
```

implement `onResponse` and `onFailure`:

```
if (response.isSuccess()) {
  if(networkResponseCallback!=null)
       networkResponseCallback.onSuccess(response.body());


public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.i("Fail", "Failure ten " + t.toString());
    networkResponseCallback.onFailure();
}
```

Call the `getLastTenMessageCallBack` method like this:

```
getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, int sender_id, int offset_number, RESTDatabaseDAO service, new NetworkResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Messages> messages) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I can get the values from response.body() but how can I use it in other place? I don't want to do many thing inside onResponse() method.

Comment: If you want to update your views from `response`, just call method passing it `response.body()` as parameter.

Comment: I'm confusing about this  `call method passing it response.body() as parameter` . Could you give me some lines of code about it?

Comment: It will work because I am using this way. But I use getLastTenMessageCallBack() method many time in many place so I want it return data of reponse for easy to use.

Comment: You can't return data from `getLastTenMessageCallBack()` because that calls an `asynchronous` method. That is NOT possible.

Comment: Great answer but I want to use data return from that method in many class not in just one class. So the the we use requestCode maybe not useful. Do you have anymore solution for this?

Comment: It's seems like a kind of design pattern, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, whenever you are calling a asynchronous method, you do pass a callback to receive it.

Answer (score 2):

First, your method
`public ArrayList<Message> getLastTenMessageCallBack(...)` has synchronous signature, but implementation is asynchronous. So when method returns `messages` , they are still empty.

Correct signature with asynchronous impl would be

```
public void getLastTenMessageCallBack(...)
```

where result can be obtained only in callback.

If you want have a synchronous method you may use latch:

```
public ArrayList<Message> getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, int sender_id, int offset_number, RESTDatabaseDAO service) {

    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Call<ArrayList<Message>> call = service.getLastTenMessage(user_id, sender_id, offset_number);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Response<ArrayList<Message>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {

                messages = response.body();
                latch.countDown();
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("Fail", "Failure ten " + t.toString());
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    //waiting result ...
    latch.await();
    return messages;
}
```

Note, there is no variables out of method scope.

**upd**
What if you want to have asynchronous method and want use it from many classes. Correct signature would be:

```
public void getLastTenMessageCallBack(..., Callback<ArrayList<Message>>)
```

and you will implement this callback in client code. Async method more preferable of course, so it avoid ui blocking

Comment: I tried but it make the application stop and the emulator screen become black.

Comment: You're right about asynchronous method but maybe I have some issue with Latch, let me try again,

Comment: Solution how turn asynchronous code to a synchronous is correct, but i haven't tested this code of course.

Comment: Tried but still not successful :D anyway, thank you.

Comment: There is only one way to make this call sync. Also i update answer, because async way more preferable...

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a locally scoped variable called "messages" in your anonymous inner class that will hide the outer class variable.  Try removing that line and adding the messages member variable back into your class object.

Comment: I tried to define a ArrayList<Message> messages variable with private in top of file and get data by messages = response.body() but still not success.

Comment: Rohit Arya is correct about the asychronous part.  You're returning messages from this method, but probably nothing has happened yet - so messages will be empty when the function returns.  You probably really want to be updating some UI element instead of just modifying messages.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it'll work.  Might need some messing about with synchronization so the UI update happens on the correct thread (been eons since I wrote a java UI sorry)

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with having a global variable, but you never assigned any value to this variable, all you did was declare a local variable in the function `onResponse()`, the SCOPE of this variable is just inside that function `onResponse()` so anywhere outside that function that variable won't exist.

So by declaring a variable `messages` which is scoped to the enclosing class, you can now directly assign the response body to the "class scoped" `messages` variable

This should do it,

```
private List<Message> messages;
public ArrayList<Message> getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, int sender_id, int offset_number, RESTDatabaseDAO service) {
    Call<ArrayList<Message>> call = service.getLastTenMessage(user_id, sender_id, offset_number);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Response<ArrayList<Message>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                // This is wrong you are creating a new variable
                // messages scoped to this function.
                // List<Message>  messages = response.body();
                // Instead just assign the response body to the class
                // scoped variable messages
                messages = response.body();
                Log.i("Success", "Good ten " + response.body().size());
            } else {
                Log.i("Success", "Not good  ten" + response.raw());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("Fail", "Failure ten " + t.toString());
        }
    });
    Log.i("Success", "Good ten activity" + messages.size());
    return messages;
}
```

**EDIT**

> should we use some way to make the return of
>   getLastTenMessageCallBack() later then onResponse?

The above function `getLastTenMessagesCallBack` will always return null, because the `onResponse` function is called after the success of your Retrofit call, so you cannot be returning anothing from the function `getLastTenMessagesCallBack` because the messages variable wont be set until the callback from your retrofit call is called, so the solution for this is,

First you create an interface to that has a function which takes in the result of your Retrofit call

```
public interface MyCustomCallback {
    void onSuccess(Object result);

    void onError(Object errorObject);
}
```

then you pass in an implementation of this interface to the `getLastTenMessageCallBack`

```
public void getLastTenMessageCallBack(int user_id, int sender_id, int offset_number, RESTDatabaseDAO service, final MyCustomCallback callback) {
    Call<ArrayList<Message>> call = service.getLastTenMessage(user_id, sender_id, offset_number);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Response<ArrayList<Message>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                // This is wrong you are creating a new variable
                // messages scoped to this function.
                // List<Message>  messages = response.body();
                // Instead just assign the response body to the class
                // scoped variable messages
                messages = response.body();
                callback.onSuccess(messages);
                Log.i("Success", "Good ten " + response.body().size());
            } else {
                Log.i("Success", "Not good  ten" + response.raw());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("Fail", "Failure ten " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

So remember while calling `getLastTenMessageCallback` you need to pass an **Implementation** of the interface, an example implementation of the interface I just created would look like this

```
class CallbackImpl implements MyCustomCallback {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object result) {
        List<Message> messages = (List<Message>) result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Object errorObject) {

    }
}
```

P.S you can refine this further by using generics in the callback interface just like how retrofit does for instance

Comment: I've just updated my question. I create a private like above but still cannot get the values outside that class :D

Comment: Since you already initialized messages with `new ArrayList()` just do `messages.addAll(response.body())`

Comment: Also make sure that this code is actually getting executed and your `response.body()` actually has list of messages in it

Comment: Yes, I tried this solution but still not success. And the response.body() return exactly data of list from Json.

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy ofcourse the messages that is returned from the function `getLastTenMessageCallBack` will be null, because `onResponse` function is executed after the function `getLastTenMessageCallBack` returns.

Comment: should we use some way to make the return of getLastTenMessageCallBack() later then onResponse? :D

Comment: Why do we create a new interface? Maybe simple use callback, that retrofit provides `Callback<ArrayList<Message>>()`?

Comment: @zella yep that works too :)  but I like to abstract out all http related errors right here and not bother ui layer with it